# problems when loading a deep learning model(python)

Tags: python, model, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a model on another PC and when I load the model on my laptop,
something is going wrong.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
model=load_model("resnet.hdf5")
```

The following is the error I got:

```
c:\users\junpink\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site- 
packages\h5py\_hl\base.py in _e(self, name, lcpl)

135         else:

136             try:

--> 137                 name = name.encode('ascii')

138                 coding = h5t.CSET_ASCII

139             except UnicodeEncodeError:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anyone have solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Python versions between the two machines. This looks to be a Python 2 vs. Python 3 issue, but I can't really be sure.

For a "quick-and-dirty" fix, try changing:

```
name = name.encode('ascii')
```

to

```
name = str(name).encode('ascii')
```

Comment: well later I try training model on the same machine, same problems occur.

Comment: I have checked the source code of model saving in Keras, and it uses a lot of encode&decode functions. I'm wondering if they forget to remove it while updating to python3.